# Blinking Video/SurfaceView when resizing to PiP mode

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer, android-picture-in-picture

I'm working on [PiP mode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture) in my app. In fact it is working pretty fine, but I have a problem with blinking/disappearing video for a split second.

I have VideoActivity in "fullscreen"/normal mode. I'm calling `enterPictureInPictureMode();` and `Activity` is collapsing to small PiP-frame. At the moment when animation is ending shrinking layout then video get transparent for a split second/one frame. Also exacly in this frame whole PiP-frame gets shadow under (elevation). When I touch this small PiP-frame it expands a bit to big PiP-frame (not fullscreen) and this anim is smooth, but when auto-collapse to small PiP-frame it blinks again on the end... Everytime when `Activity` is animating to small PiP-frame (no matter if is collapsing from big PiP-frame or fullscreen `Activity`) one-frame transparency-blink occurs when reaching final "small bounds". No impact to sound, video is playing steady, no calls to `onPlayerStateChanged`.

With newer API version we can create animation with bounds and thats how I know the video **view** is blinking... Using no-attribute method makes whole layout collapses and I can see blink only on area with video/player/surface view (black stripes above and below video). When I use newer method and `setSourceRectHint` I can see whole PiP-frame disapears without respecting black background of its parent. In fact I've added dummy `View` with fixed size, background color and `centerInParent` like `PlayerView` - it blinks/hides just like player when is placed **below** (first in parent) `PlayerView` layer, but placed **above** doesn't blink at all and is showing above `PlayerView` even when it disappears for split sec.

How to fix that blink or maybe though set black background, not transparent...

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    playerView.getVideoSurfaceView().getDrawingRect(bounds);
    int toTop = (playerView.getMeasuredHeight() - bounds.height()) / 2,
        toLeft = (playerView.getMeasuredWidth() - bounds.width()) / 2;
    bounds.top += toTop;
    bounds.left += toLeft;
    bounds.bottom += toTop;
    bounds.right += toLeft;
    enterPictureInPictureMode(new PictureInPictureParams.Builder().
        setSourceRectHint(bounds).
        setAspectRatio(new Rational(bounds.width(), bounds.height())).
        build());
} else
    enterPictureInPictureMode();
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/activity_video_player_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    app:controller_layout_id="@layout/exo_custom_control_view"
    app:fastforward_increment="10000"
    app:rewind_increment="10000"
    app:show_timeout="100" />
    ...
```

PS. Above problem also appears when using usual `VideoView` played in `WebView` and got into fullscreen by [VideoEnabledWebChromeClient](https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/name/cpr/VideoEnabledWebChromeClient.java). But in this case blink reveals for a split second part of `WebView`s content

edit: I've just found a workaround for blinking ExoPlayer - by replacing `SurfaceView` with `TextureView`, adding `app:surface_type="texture_view"` - but I'm reading that `TextureView` is a bit less efficient and also this is not fixing `VideoView` blink (fullscreen from `WebView`)

edit2: can confirm blinks on Android 8 (Xiaomi) and 9 (Pixel)

Comment: Did you check with Netflix or any other video playing app which uses the PiP feature? I am asking this because, I have seen in some phones that the GPU is not capable of rendering secure video (playready/widevine drm content) and during the transition it might be possible to use GPU if the display layers are more than 5-6 (HWC has some limit).